# UITableView not reusing custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My `UITableView` keep redrawing my custom cell whenever it scrolls out of view. I am using a subclassed `UITableViewCell`. I believe the problem to be where I'm calling my methods in `layoutSubviews`. Here is the code for the tableView:

```
- (void)setupTableView
{
  [self.facitlityTableView setDataSource:self];
  [self.facitlityTableView setDelegate:self];
  [self.facitlityTableView registerClass:[FacilityTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
  [self.facitlityTableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
  return 3;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return 90;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  FacilityTableViewCell *cell = (FacilityTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = (FacilityTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
  }

  return cell;
}
```

And here is the code for the `FacilityTableViewCell`

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
  [super layoutSubviews];
  [self setupLogo];
  [self setupCompanyName];
  [self isOpen];
  [self setupProvidesList];
}

- (void)setupLogo
{
  self.letter = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.height/1.25, self.frame.size.height-2)];
  [self.letter setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
  [self.letter setText:@"K"];
  [self.letter setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
  [self.letter setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:40]];
  [self.letter setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
  [self.letter setAlpha:0.7];
  [self addSubview:self.letter];
}

- (void)setupCompanyName
{
  self.companyName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.letter.frame.size.width + kUIPadding, kUIPadding, 0, 0)];
  [self.companyName setText:@"Company Name"];
  [self.companyName setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f]];
  [self.companyName sizeToFit];
  [self.companyName setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
  [self addSubview:self.companyName];
}

- (void)setupProvidesList
{
  self.providesList = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.letter.frame.size.width + kUIPadding, self.companyName.frame.size.height + kUIPadding, self.frame.size.width - (self.letter.frame.size.width + kUIPadding), 40)];
  [self.providesList setNumberOfLines:2];
  [self.providesList setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
  [self.providesList setText:@"Food, Hot Drinks, Food, Hot Drinks, Food, Hot Drinks, Food, Hot Drinks, Food, Hot Drinks"];
  [self addSubview:self.providesList];
}

- (void)isOpen
{
  self.open = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.companyName.frame.size.width+kUIPadding,kUIPadding,self.companyName.frame.size.height,self.companyName.frame.size.height)];
  self.open.alpha = 0.5;
  self.open.layer.cornerRadius = self.companyName.frame.size.height/2;
  self.open.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  [self addSubview:self.open];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
  [self.letter removeFromSuperview];
  [self.companyName removeFromSuperview];
  [self.providesList removeFromSuperview];
  [self.open removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Never add subviews from `layoutSubview`. The only thing you should ever do in `layoutSubviews` is to update the frames of subviews. `layoutSubview` will be called many times.

Comment: Where should I put those methods?

Comment: In the appropriate init method for the cell class.

Comment: Better yet, create and configure the subviews in the nib file -- that's what it's for.

Comment: As an aside, you put all your view code into a method that's going to be called every time the cell scrolls into view, and then somehow came to the conclusion that the cell wasn't being reused.  You need to apply more critical thought before making such a claim.